# Show items with high inventory first

Tags: magento

I want to show my customers products that are high in inventory first so as to clear the inventory fast. How to I to do this in magento 1.7.2?

I installed this extension “Creatuity corp Sort by” but need to manually click sort by quantity. I need to do this by default.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can go throw this steps

To do this a good post is [Click](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/203590/#t345652) on

A more elegant solution is to make changes in

```
.../Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php at line #102

$collection->joinField('inventory_in_stock', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id','is_in_stock>=0', 'left')->setOrder('inventory_in_stock', 'desc');
```

This will effect both the listing as well as the results page.

Another things is to remember to copy this file from core to

```
code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php
```

so that the core files remain as it is.

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: I got an error "Fatal error: Call to a member function joinField() on a non-object in C:\xampp-portable\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer.php on line 102.

Comment: have copied Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php and just you have to add above code

Comment: I tried copied to code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/ and replace the line #102 with your code. Am L doing something wrong?

Comment: have refer my detail link ?

Comment: yes but still got error. how to insert code without getting the error? do I need to edit the database? Can explain in detail? Thank for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use my free extension. It doesn't brake sorting-by-price functionality.

https://github.com/MaximusDecimus/ShowInStockFirst

Tested with 1.8.0.0

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly copy the file from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php` to this folder `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php`, create the categories if do not exist already.

Edit the following line round line #86:

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
```

to:

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()->joinField('inventory_in_stock', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id','is_in_stock>=0', 'left')->setOrder('inventory_in_stock','desc');
```

Hope this works :)